# move-assignment operator is defined as deleted if the class has a const member?

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

It says "Like the Copy-assignment operator, the move-assignment operator is defined as deleted if the class has a const or reference member." in *C++ Primer 5th* Section 13.6 .

And I write a demo like below.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    A() : mem(0) {}
    const int mem;
};

int main()
{
    A a1, a2 = std::move(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

It has `const` member in class `A` but why it can be compiled successfully? What I missed?

Answer (score 4):

Because this is not assigment, but initialization. `a2` is initialized from `std::move(a1)` via the move constructor, but not move assignment operator.

You'll get the error if you change the code to:

```
A a1;
A a2;
a2 = std::move(a1); // assignment
```